# Cannot get parameters from PHP when using Volley with JsonObjectRequest

Tags: php, android, json

I am using the Volley framework with JsonObjectRequest request. I am using

```
JsonObjectRequest loginRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(b.toString(), params,
        new Listener<JSONObject>() {},
                    new Response.ErrorListener() {});
```

The `params` variable contains the parameters and it is a JSONObject.

The problem is that I cannot access any of these variables in my PHP code. $_POST or $_REQUEST variables gives me nothing.

I also tried something like below but no luck.

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

Answer (score 7):

I encountered the same problem while using Volley with my PHP API. Turns out, a `JSONObject` of params is sent along as JSON. Therefore, PHP $_POST won't recognize it because it isn't in the format: `param1=value1&param2=value`

To see for yourself try: `print file_get_contents("php://input");`

The solution for me was to create a workaround class that extends `Request<JSONObject>` instead of using `JsonObjectRequest`

```
import com.android.volley.Request;
import com.android.volley.Response;
import com.android.volley.AuthFailureError;
import com.android.volley.NetworkResponse;
import com.android.volley.ParseError;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.HttpHeaderParser;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

/**
* Custom Request Class for JSON
*/
public class CustomRequest extends Request<JSONObject> {

    private List params; // the request params
    private Response.Listener<JSONObject> listener; // the response listener

    public CustomRequest(int requestMethod, String url, List params,
        Response.Listener<JSONObject> responseListener, Response.ErrorListener errorListener) {

        super(requestMethod, url, errorListener); // Call parent constructor
        this.params = params;
        this.listener = responseListener;
    }

    // We have to implement this function
    @Override
    protected void deliverResponse(JSONObject response) {
        listener.onResponse(response); // Call response listener
    }

    // Proper parameter behavior
    @Override
    public Map <String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
        Map <String, String> map = new HashMap <String, String>();

        // Iterate through the params and add them to our HashMap
        for (BasicNameValuePair pair: params) {
            map.put(pair.getName(), pair.getValue());
        }

        return map;
    }

    // Same as JsonObjectRequest#parseNetworkResponse
    @Override
    protected Response<JSONObject> parseNetworkResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
        try {
            String jsonString = new String(response.data, HttpHeaderParser.parseCharset(response.headers));
            return Response.success(new JSONObject(jsonString),
            HttpHeaderParser.parseCacheHeaders(response));
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(e));
        } catch (JSONException je) {
            return Response.error(new ParseError(je));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Yes, this is unfortunately the problem. It does solve the issue with your custom request class.

Comment: Your blog post link is dead.  :(

Comment: @NightlyNexus sorry about that, it should be fixed now!

Comment: @kxc1013 you just save my day..hahahaha